# How to verify username and password in Java-mysql?

Tags: java, passwords

How do I verify in the most right way the username and password that were inputted by the user to the database?

```
In c++, we used to verify by using if-else:
    if((user == "username")&&(pass == "password")){
             cout<<"You are now logon!";
    }
```

In java-mysql I'm not sure if I'm on the right track:

Login Button

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        user = jTextField1.getText();
        pass = jPasswordField1.getPassword();
        login();
}
```

Method/function

```
private void login() {

        try {
                if (user != null) {
                sql = "Select * from users_table Where username='" + user + "'";
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

                rs.next();
                username = rs.getString("username");
                password = rs.getString("password");

            }
        } 
    catch (SQLException err) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, err.getMessage());
        }

}
```

If the username and password that inputted by the user matched with the ones in the database then he will be directed to a new jFrame else
message dialog will popup saying invalid username or password. Can someone help me with my codes, I don't know how to use the if-else statement with mysql;

Thanks! :)

Comment: you save passwords in clear text? hope this is not going to be deployed.

Comment: You're not using PreparedStatement to guard against SQL injection...you're getting the values back in plaintext...well, those are the two major issues I see.  I also don't see where you're actually doing any comparison on the value of the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the below code:

```
private void login() {
    try {
        if (user != null && pass != null) {
            String sql = "Select * from users_table Where username='" + user + "' and password='" + pass + "'";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            if (rs.next()) {
                //in this case enter when at least one result comes it means user is valid
            } else {
                //in this case enter when  result size is zero  it means user is invalid
            }
        }

        // You can also validate user by result size if its comes zero user is invalid else user is valid

    } catch (SQLException err) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, err.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: This will work but it is dangerous as it allows easy SQL injection. You should be using PreparedStatement instead of concating select script on your own. So: connection.prepareStatement("select * from user_table where username = ? and password = ?"); p.setString(1, "Tom") ....

Comment: This solution showcases two **extremely** bad practices: concatenating dirty strings allowing SQL injection, and assuming that passwords are stored verbatim in the database. As is, it's actively harmful.

Comment: Besides issues with SQL injection, and plain text passwords, in java is recommended to use char[] instead of String for passwords

Comment: **Username:** `admin`  **Password:** `' OR password <> '`

Answer (score 2):

- Always store Hash encrypted passwords in database, refer [JASYPT](http://www.jasypt.org/encrypting-passwords.html) for more details on encrypting passwords
- Encrypt the password entered by the user and compare the two encrypted passwords
- Use [parametrized queries](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) while querying database

Comment: Remember that hashing is not encryption. You should store **hashed** passwords. JASYPT have the right idea, i.e. salt + iterate your hash.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to do anything with mySQL anymore. You already have the credentials.
One Example:

```
if ((user.equals(username)) && (pass.equals(password))) {
   JFrame newFrame = new JFrame();
} else {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "alert", "alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
}
```

Comment: user and password are the user's input right? then username and password are the resultsets? username = rs.getString("username");
                password = rs.getString("password"); right? @_@

Comment: uhm...according to YOUR source... user and pass are the user entries, password and username thefields from the database...

Comment: strings should be compared with `equals` not with `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Use prepared statements along with a library like DButils which would simplify your work a lot.

In addition, don't use substitution pass parameters such as `select name from members where code =?`. If you have many parameters, create a array of objects and pass them in a object array such as `Objects[] parms = {code1,code2}`.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (username.length()>0 && password.length()>0)
{
    String query = "Select * from adminlogin Where Username='" + username + "' and Password='" + password + "'";

    rs = sta.executeQuery(query);

   if (rs.next()) 
   {

        home hme=new home();
        this.setVisible(false);
        hme.setVisible(true);
   } 
   else 
   {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"username and password are wrong ");
   }
}
else
{
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"please field username and password ");
}
```